# Get the data passed to an ejs file in an included js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am using express js and rendering an file using

```
res.render('plain',{state:'admin'})
```

where plain.ejs is an ejs file. This file has an include main.js

```
<script src ="/main.js"></script>
```

How can i access the state variable in the main.js file ,please help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly.
But you can do something like this :

plain.ejs

```
<script>
var state = {{ state }};
</script>
<script src ="/main.js"></script>
```

then in main.js

```
console.log(state);
```

Comment: I tried, but I'm getting an error       Uncaught Syntax error : Unexpected token {

Comment: what is your delimiter for ejs ?

Comment: Got it ! the delimiter is <%- %> and i used     var state = <%- JSON.stringify(state) %>         now i am able to use it in main.js,                        Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hey.I get an error property assignment expected in the line var state = {{ state }}; Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Possibly dirty solution but you could create the state variable in global scope and main.js will be able to access it:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var state = '<%= state%>'
</script>

<script src ="/main.js"></script>
```

If you have more data to be passed to the client you could pass it as an object:

```
res.render('plain',{data: {state:'admin', page_title: 'first page'}})
```

And then just output the whole object like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var data = <%= JSON.stringify(data)%>
</script>
```

This way you could access the state as by `data.state`.